# Torch: Run Multiple (identical graph but different weights) Models in parallel on one GPU

Tags: pytorch

I have a large GPU and many small models to train. Each model has exactly the same architecture, but different weights, i.e. I have multiple instances of the same Module.
Since the Models are small, and hyperparam optimization shows a surprisingly small batchsize is necessary/optimal, the only way to make efficient use of the GPU would be to be able to run multiple models at once form what I understand. There are two slightly different solutions, an answer to either would be helping me out a lot:
(1) Can I run multiple instances of the same model (same architecture, different weights) on the same data, i.e. the same minibatch in parallel somehow?
(2) Can I run multiple instances of the same model (same architecture, different weights) on different minibatches in parallel somehow?

I'm looking for a solution to this in Torch.